# How can I return a list of 40 distinct objects when pulling only the userName value(s) from a JSONArray?

Tags: java, json, for-loop

I have a JSONArray in which I need to pull only the userName value(s) and then map those usernames
to key value pair {"username": "name"}.  There are 40 names.

When I return I do get 40 items back but it is the last username in the list 40 times.

How do I return the list of 40 distinct objects?

In the below getJsonUsername method I pass the entire list and an empty string.
Within the method  I loop over the list and pull the "username" key.

I can see all 40 usernames via debugger when looping in proper format {"username": "amyT"} {"username": "johnH"}...etc.

How do I return the list of 40 distinct objects?

```
listUsersJson =  getUserInfo();

String users = "";
JSONArray listofUserNames = getJsonUsername(listUsersJson, users);
        
//Prints only the last userName from list 40 times.  
logger.info("************listofUserNames************ " + 
listofUserNames);

        
private JSONArray getJsonUsername(JSONArray listUsersJson,
 String users )   throws JSONException {

JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();

for (int index = 0; index < listUsersJson.length(); ++index)
 {
   JSONObject users = listUsersJson.getJSONObject(index);
   userName = users.getString("userName");

   jsonObject.put("userName", userName);

   jsonArray.put(jsonObject);
  }
    return jsonArray;
 }
```

Comment: You only create one JSONObject and you keep updating it over and over again which modifies it to have just the latest user name. And you add it to the JSONArray over and over again, so the final array will have just one, identical object repeated over and over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only create one `JSONObject` and you keep updating it over and over again which modifies it to have just the latest user name. And you add it to the `JSONArray` over and over again, so the final array will have just one, identical object repeated over and over.

Move the creation of `jsonObject` into the loop, right before the `put`.